# Truck won't start

Tags: chevrolet, starting, troubleshooting

My truck turns over for a second , maybe two and then stops cranking.  It will do it over and over. A few days ago my ECM touched a hot battery terminal and that's when it started acting up. Does anyone know if the ECM could be fried?  Or could it be something else?  My batteries are good, I had them checked and had to replace one of them. But now I'm stumped. I feel like it's probably a bad ECM now!?  Any help would be appreciated.

Hey guys my truck is an 06 silverado 6.6 4x. Thx for the responses so far.   I think it may have been because i put the truck inside the shop at my work but it did start the night after I first posted this. It died on me a few times but started right back up. It ran for a total of about 30-40 min. The next morning I started it and pulled it forward a little then worked on it with the garage door open and it wouldn't start later that day. Hasn't started since. It's been between 0- 30 degrees around here for a month now. I think I may need to add some additives to the fuel. I also got some codes off of it I can post when I get home later, maybe that will help you guys help me!

Comment: What year and model is your vehicle. Will help us diagnose your issues.

Comment: Just to make sure: that's 0-30 degrees Fahrenheit, right?

Comment: Or you may want to check your ignition switch. Chevys are prone to ignition switch failures more so in the cold.

Answer (score 2):

To take the load off of any ECU output your starter system will have a relay to connect the starter solonoid.

If you have a drivers handbook, check for the position of the starter relay. Substitute the relay before doing anything else.

An alternative to an actual relay substitution is jump the terminals 30 and 87 together wire side, preferably with a switched fused jumper wire. This will bypass the relay.

If every thing is now OK, then it's job done,replace the relay with new. If this does not allow you to start the vehicle and the problem is still there then you will need to have a scan and a check over for communications with the ECU.